# Carregar lista com entity

Tags: c#, linq, wpf, expressões-lambda

O seguinte. Criei uma classe de contexto herdada de `DbContext`.

```
public class SiloContext : DbContext
    {
        public SiloContext()
            : base("inetConn")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Balanca> Balancas { get; set; }
    }
```

Bem, aí criei uma outra classe para carregar as informações de Produto, tendo por base a classe de Contexto.

```
public class ListaProdutos
{
    private SiloContext contexto = new SiloContext();

    public List<Produto> listaProdutos()
    {
        var prod = // O que colocar aqui? Tentei linq e nada, count == 0 e existe registros no banco.
        //return prod;
    }
}
```

Se a classe acima funcionar, então no formulário no clique do botão, deveria carregar ou num ListBox, num Grid e etc...

Alterei a minha model para isso e funcionou, mas o Linq leva o mérito, por isso eu marquei a resposta dele.

```
[Table("Produto")]
    public class Produto
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int idProduto { get; set; }
        public string NMProduto { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que acessar a propriedade `Produtos` do seu contexto.

```
public class ListaProdutos
{
    private SiloContext contexto = new SiloContext();

    public List<Produto> listaProdutos()
    {
        return contexto.Produtos.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu já fiz isso e o count continua 0.

Comment: Então é porque não tem dados @pnet

Comment: Só me responda o seguinte: Na minha model, eu preciso informar alguma coisa, tipo, mapear a tabela ou apenas get;set;? Se for isso, está faltando alguma coisa. Eu fiz apenas na model, o get e set.

Comment: A princípio, não precisa. Como é o nome da tabela do banco de dados? Ela foi gerada pelo EF também?

Comment: Não, o banco já existia. Fazer uma mapeamento, creio que é o certo, ok? Com Fluent ou similares. Se sim, esse mapeamento eu faço em uma outra classe de mapeamento, estou certo? E não na model.

Comment: Como é o nome da tabela do banco de dados?

Comment: Produto, esse é o nome da tabela

Comment: Em cima do nome da classe `Produto` coloque um atributo assim **`[Table("Produto")]`**. Vai ser preciso adicionar o namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`